# bundling failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, babeljs

After installing react-if package to my react native app I am getting the error

> bundling failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with
>   "6.26.3"

I tried to upgrad Babel by running `npx babel-upgrade --write --install` but I am still getting the same error. How do you upgrade Babel?

If I run `babel -V` the version is 7.2.3 (@babel/core 7.4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you need to install `babel-core` .

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 @babel/core regenerator-runtime
```

try this out.

Hope it works !

Comment: Thank you for the reply I can the command but no luck still the same error.